# Getting Values from 3 Models where 1 model is the main root using Lambda/Linq EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to retrieve data from database using EF.

I have 3 these 3 sample models

```
public class Info { 
    [Key] public int InfoId {get;set;}
    public string infoName {get;set;}

    public ICollection<SubInfo> SubInfo {get;set;}
 }

 public class SubInfo { 
    [Key] public int SubInfoId {get;set;}
    public string subInfoName {get;set;}

    public Info Info {get;set}
    public int InfoId {get;set;}
    public ICollection<SubSubInfo> SubSubInfo {get;set;}
 }

 public class SubSubInfo { 
    [Key] public int SubSubInfoId {get;set;}
    public string subInfoName {get;set;}

    public SubInfo SubInfo {get;set}
    public int SubInfoId {get;set;}
 }
```

The models about explain: `Info` is the main while `SubInfo` is the sub of main Info, and `SubSubInfo` is the sub of sub info details.

So far, I'm using this similar code to retrieve data and it works fine

```
var info = context.Info.Include(x=>x.SubInfo).ToList();
```

But the problem is, the SubSubInfo is empty inside the result.

I've tried this: `var info = context.Info.Include(x=>x.SubInfo.Select((y=>y.SubSubInfo)));` but I'm getting an error that says: `InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'x => ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use multiple include, you have to first include your first level.
In your sample:

```
var info = context.Info.Include(x=> x.SubInfo)
                       .Include(x=> x.SubInfo.Select(y=> y.SubSubInfo ));
```

Also you can use ThenInclude() if you using EF Core.
See link below for further information 
http://entityframework.net/include-multiple-levels

Comment: I tried it. But it throws an error that says similar `InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from SubInfo y in x.SubInfo select [y].SubSubInfo}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'.`

Comment: But since, I'm using EF Core, `ThenInclude()` works fine. Thank you sir for the tip

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve could be easily done with **Eager Loading** which can be read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) or [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx). The error you are getting is that you cannot combine **LINQ** with raw **SQL** (`Include` and `Select` in your case).

<s>In other words, you are trying to **Load Multiple Entities** which can be achieved by using a code similar to:</s>

```
var info = context.Info.Include("SubInfo.SubSubInfo").ToList();
```

*Edit start*

You want to Load Multiple Levels which is achieved with the `Include` and `ThenInclude` methods. An example would be

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ToList();
}
```

and for your context it would be:

```
var info = context.Info.
           Include(subInfo => subInfo.SubInfo).
           ThenInclude(subSubInfo => subSubInfo.SubSubInfo).
           ToList();
```

where `SubInfo` and `SubSubInfo` are the navigation properties from your models. Also take in consideration you have to mention if you are using **.NET Core** or **.NET Framework** since **.NET Core** doesn't support **Lazy Loading**.

But I see that @AliJP already answered on your question.

*Edit end*

If you want to read more about this topic try reading about **Eager Loading** and **Lazy Loading**.

Comment: I'm having an error that says `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I've edited my post since now I see that I've made a mistake.